# 特定の文字列を含む行にフラグを立てる関数を作成したい

Tags: python, pandas

下記のデータフレームに対し、

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({'pref': ['東京都', '神奈川県', '北海道', '埼玉県', '千葉県', '静岡県',
> '長野県'],
>                    'city' : ['渋谷区', '横浜市', '函館市', '浦和市', '浦安市' , '浜松市', '岡谷市']})
```

"1都3県 or その他" を格納する「pref_flg」という列を追加する関数を定義したいです。

出来上がるデータフレームのイメージは下記の通りです。

```
> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'pref': ['東京都', '神奈川県', '北海道', '埼玉県', '千葉県',
> '静岡県', '長野県'],
>                     'city' : ['渋谷区', '横浜市', '函館市', '浦和市', '浦安市' , '浜松市', '岡谷市'],
>                     'pref_flg' : ['1都3県', '1都3県', 'その他', '1都3県', '1都3県' , 'その他', 'その他']})
```

下記のように `'文字列' in ●` を使うことを考えましたが、
文字列が１個の場合は正しく処理できるようなのですが、
文字列が２個以上ある場合の書き方が分かりません。

```
def get_pref(x):
        if '東京都' in x:   # ここを複数の文字列に指定する方法が分からない
            return '1都3県'
        else:
            return 'その他'

df['pref_flg'] = df['pref'].apply(get_pref)
```

アドバイスいただけますと幸いです。

++++++++ 追記
下記を試してみたところ、想定の結果となりました。

```
prefs = ['東京都', '神奈川県', '千葉県', '埼玉県']
def get_pref(x):
    global prefs
    if x in prefs:
        return '1都3県'
    else:
        return 'その他'

df5['pref_flg'] = df5['pref'].apply(get_pref)
```

Comment: `'東京都' in x` ではなく、逆に考えてみてはどうでしょうか。`x in ('東京都', '神奈川県', '埼玉県', '千葉県')`

Comment: @metropolis さま、 早々にありがとうございます。文法的に、文字列 in x だと思っていたのですが・・・、逆もＯＫなんですね？なお、、実際に処理したいデータでは、判定したい文字列がurlで20程あり、x in ( '●●', '●●' ... )　と括弧内にベタ書きすると見づらくなってしまうので、、何らかの形で（関数内でまず判定用の文字列のリストを作成するとか？）対処できたらと考えています。こちらも色々試してみたのですが想定の結果が得られず、、このあたりも可能であればアドバイスいただけませんでしょうか？

Comment: 20程ある url のリストを関数内ではなく、main ブロック(global scope)で定義しておいても良いのではないでしょうか。差し支えがなければ、そちらで試してみたコードを追記してみて下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます。関数内でglobal変数の定義が必要、ということを知りませんでした。。ネットでリサーチし、こうかな？と思う内容を本文に追記してみました。いちおう想定の結果にはなりましたが、この書き方で問題ないでしょうか・・・？こうすることで、リストではなく、リストの中の文字列を、関数内で参照できるようになっているのですよね？？

Comment: はい、問題はありませんが、`global prefs` は不要です(入れておいても構いませんが)。

Comment: ありがとうございます。関数定義内で「global prefs」は必須ではないのですね・・・。ちなみに、x in y の文法についてですが、これまで認識していた内容ですと、【x in yとしたとき、xがyに含まれている（xがyの部分文字列である）とTrue、含まれていないとFalseが返される】であり、「prefs in ●」と記載するのかと思っていたのですが、それだとエラーになり、「● in prefs」という記述で、正常に処理できるようになりました。これまでの理解と逆の書き方なのですが、いまいち使い分けが分かっておらず・・・、よろしければ補足ご説明いただけませんでしょうか・・・？

Comment: `x` と `y` がどちらとも文字列の場合には ogawa さんの理解で正しいのですが、今回の場合は `x in y` の `y` が**文字列のリスト**になっています。この場合は「`x`(文字列) が `y`(文字列のリスト)に含まれている場合に `True`、含まれていないと `False` が返される」ことになります。

Comment: なるほど！！！完全にごっちゃになっていました。ようやく理解がクリアになりました。大変参考になりました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @metropolis  さま　先日アドバイスいただいた「x(文字列) が y(文字列のリスト)に含まれている場合に True、含まれていないと False が返される」を使った処理を試しています。こちらですが、「x（文字列）が y（文字列のリスト）の【文字列の一部】が含まれている場合にTrue、含まれていないと False が返される」といった応用も可能でしょうか？？上記質問内のコードで言うと、prefs = ['東京都', '神奈川県', '千葉県', '埼玉県']を、prefs = ['東京', '神奈川', '千葉', '埼玉'] と定義した場合にも、同様の「pref_flg」が付与できるよう実装したいと考えております。（試してみたところ、応用不可のようでして、、x.str.contains(prefs) など別の関数を使って試したりしていますが思うような結果が取得できず、、よろしければアドバイスいただけますと幸いです！

Comment: この場合、[str.startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)を使う方法があります。具体的には、`get_pref()`関数の `if x in prefs:` を `if x.startswith(tuple(prefs)):` に変更します。

Comment: @metropolis さま　早々にありがとうございます。文字列の比較には、いろいろなメソッドがあるのですね、、勉強が足りませんでした。参考にさせていただきます！

Comment: @metropolis さま　ちなみに、、prefs = ['京', '奈', '葉', '玉'] といったように、含まれているかどうか判定したい文字列が、x （文字列）の頭ではなく、x の先頭・最後尾 以外のどこかに（←真ん中に限らず）含まれている場合に、同様の「pref_flg」が付与できるよう実装することも可能でしょうか？？

Comment: `if any([y in prefs for y in x[1:-1]]):` にすればよろしいかと。

Comment: @metropolis さま　 なるほど、そんな書き方ができるのですね。。とても勉強になります！なお、実際に処理したいのは、上で書かせていただいた通り「x（文字列⇒データフレームのある列です）が y（文字列のリスト）の "文字列の一部" が含まれている場合にTrue、含まれていないと False が返される」というものでして、、x の先頭から含まれている場合もあれば、xの先頭・最末尾ではないどこかに含まれている場合もあります。なので、startswith（頭から一致するもの）や、x in y の y が文字列のリスト（リスト内の文字列で "完全一致" するもの）では拾えないものが出てきてしまうため、文字列のどこかで部分一致する場合にTrue、含まれていないと False が返される、ような実装がしたいと思っています。となると、str.containsを使う形がよいのかなと考えているのですが、x.str.contains(prefs) といった書き方ではエラーになってしまいます、。（エラー：'str' object has no attribute 'str'）x、prefs ともに文字列になっていると思うのですが、このエラーについて可能でしたらアドバイスいただけませんでしょうか・・・？

Comment: 別質問を立てて下さい。

Comment: 失礼いたしました、、承知しました。

Answer (score 1):

[pandas.DataFrame.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) と [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) を使って以下の様にも書く事ができます。

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'pref': ['東京都', '神奈川県', '北海道', '埼玉県', '千葉県', '静岡県', '長野県'],
  'city': ['渋谷区', '横浜市', '函館市', '浦和市', '浦安市' , '浜松市', '岡谷市'],
}) 

df = df.assign(
  pref_flg=np.where(
    df.pref.isin(('東京都', '神奈川県', '埼玉県', '千葉県')),
    '1都3県', 'その他')
)

print(df)

      pref   city  pref_flg
0    東京都  渋谷区     1都3県
1  神奈川県  横浜市     1都3県
2    北海道  函館市     その他
3    埼玉県  浦和市     1都3県
4    千葉県  浦安市     1都3県
5    静岡県  浜松市     その他
6    長野県  岡谷市     その他
```